# What does $$('foo') mean in JavaScript source code?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following in javascript:

```
var entriesString = '';
        $$('select[id=shopId]').each(function(elem, i){
            shops[i] = elem.value;
            entries[i] = new Array();

            $$('input[id=entry'+i+']').each(function(elem, c){
                if(elem.value != '') entries[i][c] = elem.value.replace(".", "").replace(",", "."); else entries[i][c] = '0.0'
            });
            entriesString += '&entry'+i+'=' + entries[i];
            });
```

Now I'm new to JS and therefore do not know what the first `$$('select[id=shopId]')` part means.
It must be some sort of array or collection, due to the `.each` part it is followed by.
In that loop is again a nested loop that uses the loop variable i in its head.
But again, I don't know what exactly does `%%('input[...]')` mean. What kind of syntax is this?
Also, where does the data.

This is what `entryString` looks like for example:

```
&entry0=65.8,75.5,72.9,67.9,51.1,8.2,47.9&entry1=55.9,33.5,33.8,35.2,26.8,7.0,25.8
```

Thanks a lot or your help!

Comment: Looks like `Prototype` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code uses the prototype JS framework. `$$('ELEMENTNAME')` instanciates all DOM element with `ELEMENTNAME` (so i.e. all input fields) and returns them as array of objects.

with `id==xy` it returns that one with id xy

```
<input type="blah" id="xy" value="123" />
```

will be found

Answer (score 5):

That looks like the `$$` method of the Prototype library. The documentation is here:

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility#method-$$

It selects DOM elements given a CSS-style selector.

Answer (score 3):

`$$()` is not something of javascript. It seems to be likely that you're using the Prototype Javascript Framework. Here you find the documentation of `$$`: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/dollardollar/

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Prototype library.

See http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Answer (score 0):

It use a great function to get elements with css selectors.